# Giving coordinates to an object in constructor. Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a car class:

```
local car={};
local car_mt = { __index=car };
function car.new(_x, _y)
    local ncar=
    {
        img=display.newImageRect("test_car.png",50,120,true);
    }
    function ncar:set()
        self.img.xOrigin=_x;
        self.img.yOrigin=_y;
    end
    ncar:set();
    return setmetatable(ncar,car_mt);
end
return car;
```

When I call it by this:

```
local pcar=require("car")
local car1=pcar:new(200,200);
```

the x movement just doesn't work.
When I change xOrigin and yOrigin to x and y, it doesn't matter.
but when I call it like this:

```
local pcar=require("car")
local car1=pcar:new(200,200);
car1.img.x=200;
car1.img.y=200;
```

The result is ok.
Besides, car1.x is nil and I don't understand, how can img have its own coordinates without parent's ones.
What should I write in set() function to give stage x and y  to my reference of car? And is it possible to really give it to reference, not to img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the constructor without a colon

```
local car1=pcar.new(200,200);
```

Comment: And is it possible to move car reference itself?